# Detachable AMD Laptops

Tags: laptop

I'm searching a Windows 10 detachable laptop with the following characteristics

1. removable screen 13'' max 15'' (I'll use it when in travel).
2. laptop should be able to connect to any external monitor (such as the big BenQ EW3270ZL   https://www.benq.com/en-ca/monitor/video-enjoyment/ew3270zl.html ), using HDMI other other ways when the laptop screen is not connected. (I'll use this way when at home/office)
3. AMD Ryzen processor 3, 5 or 7 .
4. price under $800
5. RAM min 8GB (more is better)
6. SSD min 256 GB , no mechanical HD

Anyone knows if exists a detachable AMD Laptop with above characteristics ?

Comment: The problem with a detachable is that the processor is usually in the tablet side, seeing as they have to be used when detached. That means there's no using them "when the laptop screen is not connected". Plus they tend to use the even more extreme low power processors (e.g. Core M, Atom or the 30xxe Athlons). If you're willing to settle with foldables then basically *any* of the new buget 2-in-1s, e.g. Lenovo Flexs, HP Envys or Asus Vivobooks, will meet your requirements.